# SAT Math Question Confusion

Tags: average

I was doing a practice `new SAT Test` and was wondering exactly what this question is asking and how it got to the answer. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How many seeds are there in total? How many apples are there in total? Hence, what is the average? (These are the questions you should be asking yourself in order to get the answer)

Comment: I've added the image for you. The explanation for why $4$ is the wrong answer is also ridiculous.

Answer (score 4):

The histogram represents $2 + 0 + 4 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 3 = 12$ apples in total. Two of them have three seeds, none with four, and so forth. Thus, to find the average, we must evaluate the sum of the seeds divided by the number of apples. Can you do the rest?